# Knockout value binding not processing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently trying to use a value binding with a `select` element through Knockout. I am also using Boostrap V4 on the document (I've had issues with the two in the past).

My html for the `select` is as follows:

```
<select id="opsGroup" class="custom-select" data-bind="options: opsGroups,
                                                   optionsCaption: 'Please select...',
                                                   value: selectedOpsGroup">
</select>
```

The relevant Javascript is as follows:

```
function ViewModelTemplate(opsGroups, branchInfo) {
    var self = this;
    self.opsGroups = ko.observableArray(opsGroups);
    self.branchesByGroup = ko.observable(branchInfo);
    self.selectedOpsGroup = ko.observable();
    self.selectedBranch = ko.observable();
    self.branchesForGroup = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.branchesByGroup()[self.selectedOpsGroup()] || [];
    });
  }

  function loadBranchInfo(e) {
    var viewModel = new ViewModelTemplate(e.opsGroups, e.branchInfo);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  }
```

`opsGroups` is just an array of strings.

Whenever I try and run this I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return selectedOpsGroup }"
Message: u(...).bind is not a function
```

I've tried finding solutions to this but have failed.

Anyone have any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Was being caused by a slim version of jQuery.
Full version in use and all functioning correctly.